# La hembra del tigre - ¿"tigresa" o "tigra"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, animales

Pensaba que la hembra del "tigre" era exclusivamente "tigresa", pero el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=tigresa) indica que

> Para designar específicamente al animal hembra, se utiliza, en la lengua general, el femenino **tigresa**, aunque en algunos países americanos es normal el femenino **tigra**

para rematar con que

> En el español medieval y clásico era normal el uso de la forma **tigre** como común en cuanto al género (el/la tigre).

Dejando aparte el uso "medieval y clásico" de **la tigre**, ¿dónde se utiliza cada una de las formas?

Answer (score 5):

Según el Diccionario de Americanismos,

> [**tigra.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=waSMutV9tx0APWFMkx3)
>   **I.    1.**    f. *Ho, ES, Ni, CR, RD, Ve, Ec, Bo; Pa, Co:C,O, rur, vulg; Ar, rur.* Hembra del **tigre**, jaguar.

Expandiendo esa lista de abreviaturas, tenemos las siguientes zonas donde se escuchará *la tigra* en vez de *la tigre* o *la tigresa*:

- Honduras
- El Salvador
- Nicaragua
- Costa Rica
- La República Dominicana
- Venezuela
- Ecuador
- Bolivia

También, en las zonas rurales de las siguientes regiones, se considera vulgar (es decir, la norma culta prefiere la forma *la tigresa*)

- Panamá
- Colombia (central, oeste, partes rurales)
- Argentina (partes rurales)

Es posible que haya otras regiones, pero estas son las con la mayor probabilidad de su empleo.

Comment: Ah vale, veo que desglosaste bien cada una de las iniciales. A mí me había quedado la duda de qué es _C,O_ y el [glosario](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/sobre-la-22a-edicion-2001/abreviaturas-y-signos-empleados) no lo aclara.

Comment: @fedorqui es una lástima que, en contraste al DRAE, las abreviaturas no se desglosen automáticamente con texto emergente.  (si buscas *tigre* en el DRAE, de la abreviatura *lat.* sale *latín*, de *U. en m. ref. a la especie* sale *usado en masculino con referencia a la especie*, incluso de cosas fáciles como *m. y f.* sale *masculino y femenino*)

Comment: Cierto. Acostumbrado al DRAE, miré el código fuente de la página por si allí estaba. Pero no. Una lástima, efectivamente.